# Compare files that are listed in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a text file which contains absolute paths to files that have the same name and I'm looking to somehow compare these files will each other to see if the contents are the same.

Ideally the output would be the files that are the same.

Would using the cmp command work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `cmp` works for you.
You can use a shell function

```
compare () { cmp -s $1 $2 && echo $1 is equal to $2 ; }
```

or, if you're brave, even

```
compare () { cmp -s $1 $2 && rm $1 ; }
```

If you have a file with two filenames per line, you can edit it to
insert the function definition at the top and put a `compare` at the beginning of each line, as follows

```
% cat filenames
compare () { cmp -s $1 $2 && echo $1 is equal to $2 ; }
compare ./a/a ./b/a
compare ./e/c ./b/c
...
% sh filenames
./e/c is equal to ./b/c
...
%
```

assuming that `a`'s are different and `c`'s are equal.